# Custom Customer Address field not passing validation

Tags: customer, forms, customer-address, form-validation, customer-address-attribute

I've added a custom field to the Customer Addresses with the following UpgradeData:

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $params = [
        'label' => 'House Number',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => true,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'position' =>999,
        'system' => 0,
    ];

    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'house_number', $params);
    $customAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'house_number');
    $customAttribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_checkout', 'adminhtml_customer', 'adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
    );
    $customAttribute->save();
}
```

The field properly displays when logging into the Adminhtml area and adding a new Addresses to a customer. However, the New Address form cannot be submitted, the following error appears:

> "House Number" is a required value.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: "House Number" is a required value.]

**I do believe that it is clear that a value for House Number was submitted.**

**What else must I do to enable this field on this form, and on other forms such as the Checkout and user's own Account Information?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a custom customer attribute or custom customer address attribute, to allow Magento to save it you need to assign it to the customer attribute set.

So, in your code, after `$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'house_number', $params);`
you should add the following code:

```
$customerSetup->addAttributeToSet(
    AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
    AddressMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS,
    null,
    'house_number'
);
```

where `AddressMetadataInterface` is imported by
`use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface;`

**But...** since Magento 2.3, Magento marked **upgrade script** as **old script**, you should use **Data patch** for data modification.

The below is the data patch to add `house_number` custom customer address attribute:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/AddHouseNumberAttribute.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddHouseNumberAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $houseNumberAttributeCode = 'house_number';

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
            $houseNumberAttributeCode, [
            'label' => 'House Number',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 999,
            'system' => false,
        ]);

        $customerSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
            AddressMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS,
            null,
            $houseNumberAttributeCode
        );

        $houseNumberAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
            $houseNumberAttributeCode
        );
        $houseNumberAttribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);
        $houseNumberAttribute->save();
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tu Van! I added the `$customerSetup->addAttributeToSet()` line, and made the other changes that you suggest such as the use of `AddressMetadataInterface` instead of the strings which they represent. However, the field still is not saved, and throws the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @dotancohen As you already add `house_number` custom customer address attribute into your database, you have to remove it from database, if you still use UpgradeData script, you have to increase setup_version in `module.xml` and run bin/magento setup:upgrade command. If you choose use Data Patch, you don't need to do anything with setup_version in `module.xml`. Let me know if you need help with that, I'll tell you how.

Comment: Yes, of course, I removed it with `$customerSetup->removeAttribute(AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS, 'house_number')` first.

Comment: Yeah, `removeAttribute` function should remove your attribute.
Run `SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'house_number'` MySql command to check if `house_number` attribute was removed or not. If it does not show any records, that means the attribute was removed. Make your changes in UpgradeData or create a new Data Patch then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. P/S: I've tested the features after applying the code in my answer before sharing it with you.

Comment: Tu Van, thank you, it worked! I made a mistake with removing the element, correcting that mistake resolved the issue! **Answer accepted.** If you know how to have the fields also appear on the Customer's Account Information page and Checkout page, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll try to help you with showing the custom customer attribute in Customer Account Information on frontend, then you can investigate to make your attribute show on the checkout page. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363176/custom-attribute-on-customer-not-showing-data-in-customer-account-information

Comment: Great, thank you! I am learning a lot from you.